# How do I hit Express backend from a reactJS front?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I deployed my react + express app on heroku and i cant seem to hit the login api served in server.js.

this is the front end where it works locally and even worked a couple commits ago, but it suddenly stopped...

```
          <a href="/login">
            <Button className="app-button" variant="success" size="lg" style={{marginTop:10, color: 'black'}}>
              Log In
            </Button>{' '}
          </a>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "spotifyproj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": " https://whispering-caverns-57172.herokuapp.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-spotify-player": "^1.0.4",
    "spotify-web-api-js": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

using fetch/axios to try and hit it did not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has routing on the client side, so that `a` tag will do nothing.

You need a library like fetch or axios to launch the `post` to `/login` pointing to the url where the express server is running.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const login = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post('http://localhost/login');

  // do something with response
}

return {
  <Button onClick={() => login()}>
    Log In
  </Button>
}
```